# How to use case statement in where clause

Tags: sql

Table has many column.I just created  a sample table and shown 3 column.

```
Id Value  Code 
1  A      10
2  B      20
3  C      30
4  D      22
5  E      11
6  F      12
7  G      14
```

In select report, I am showing value of A or B or C as C,Value of D or E  as E remaining as it is 
Means I  displayed like this

```
Id Value  count
1 C      10
2 C      20
3 C      30
4 E      22
5 E      11
6 F      12
7 G      14
```

But when user select C want to compare all A,B and c in where clause when 
E want to compare D and E in where clause like this.How to use case statement here

Select * from Sample where value =

like this 
I want like this

```
Select * from Sample
 WHERE value = CASE WHEN @value = 'C' THEN A ELSE @value END
```

But here are 3 value for c like A,B,C.If i write like this

```
Select * from Sample
 WHERE value = CASE WHEN @value = 'C' THEN 'A' 
 WHEN @value = 'C' THEN 'B'
 WHEN @value = 'C' THEN 'C'
 ELSE @value END
```

then it will be wrong.

Comment: This seems more like an SQL question not Asp.NET.  What do you mean by compare all A,B and C?

Comment: Sorry, your question is really not clear.  And as @Adolfo says, what does this have to do with `asp.net`?  Please update your question with more information, including **which DBMS are you using** (SQL Server 2012, Oracle, MySql, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
declare @code nvarchar(20) = 'C'

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (@code = 'C' AND value in ('A', 'B', 'C'))
OR (@code = 'E' AND value in ('D', 'E'))
```

Comment: @artm solution will work, you just need to change `WHERE @code = 'A'` to  `WHERE @code = 'C'` because that's what the user may enter based on your report